# spring mvc 3.0 small web application not quite working

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i'm creating a very simple (hello World quality) web application using spring mvc 3.0. when deploying the application on tomcat 6.0.26 and i try to open

http://localhost:8080/protoweb/helloWorld.html

i get 404, resource /protoweb/WEB-INF/jsp/helloWorld.jsp is not available.

The funny thing is that there *IS* a helloWorld.jsp in there.

any idea what i'm doing wrong?

here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>hello-spring3-RC1</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/yummy-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>yummy</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>yummy</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

my yummy-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mine.web.controllers"/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
   <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
 </bean>
</beans>
```

my very simple controller:

```
package com.mine.web.controllers;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class BasicController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/helloWorld")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
  ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("helloWorld");
        mav.addObject("message", "Hello some basic message for u");
        return mav;

    }
}
```

and my webapp/jsp/helloWorld.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
${message}
</body>
</html>
```

also, it might be helpful to post my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mine</groupId>
  <artifactId>protoweb</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>protoweb Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>springsource maven repo</id>
  <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
 </repository>
</repositories>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0.RC1</version>
 </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>protoweb</finalName>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
         <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
           <configurationDir>tomcat</configurationDir>
                 <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
                 <username>test</username>
                 <password>test</password>
         </configuration>
  </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you sure your JSP is in `<root>/WEB-INF/jsp`, and not in `<root>/jsp` ?

Comment: that was it! thanks! i had the jsp in src/main/webapp/jsp but apparently the mvn tomcat:deploy is copying it to <root>/jsp rather than WEB-INF/jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without a proper directory listing, but your source tree should be:

```
pom.xml
src
   /main
        /java   # all your java sources
        /webapp # stuff for the web app
               /WEB-INF
                       /jsp/helloWorld.jsp
```